# Pester test evaluating type PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell, pester

I wrote a unit test in pester where it verifies the result against the returned object (a hash table) created using PSCustomObject, but I am not sure how to definite it:

```
$result = get-dataFromOverThere
$result | Should -Be [PSObject]
```

after invoking pester, I get:

```
Expected '[PSCustomObject]', but got @{ name = "bob"; company = "vance refrigeration"}.
```

it technically was the correct value I wanted, but not sure how to definite the last portion of the test

Comment: Hi, `$result -is [PSObject]` is what you are after

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the underlying types, because the comparison you have today is comparing the whole object you have in `$result` versus the Class `[PSObject]`, which won't work.  Instead, try this.

```
$result.GetType().Name | should -be 'PSCustomObject'
#or
$result.GetType().Name -eq 'PSCustomObject' | should -be $true
```

Either syntax should work, Mr. Vance.

Answer (score 0):

I should have provided more detail, but I discovered a resolution that involved creating an mock that returned a hash table with the values I required to test.  Meaning, I could actually verify the output for certain scenarios.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution to check the **actual is of expected type**:

```
Describe "return type" {
  It "should have type [pscustomobject]" {
    $actual = [pscustomobject]@{a = 1}
    $actual | Should -BeOfType [pscustomobject]
  }
}
```

Checked with PS7.0.3 and Pester 5.0.4

If you want to check the **object has only expected properties and values**, then you can do it this way:

```
# Install-Module Functional
Import-Module Functional

Describe "return values" {
  It "checks that the actual object has correct properties and values" {
    $actual = [pscustomobject]@{a = 1}
    $expected = [pscustomobject]@{"a" = 1}
    $actual, $expected | Test-Equality | Should -BeTrue
  }
}
```